# Cropping in drupal not working on ie10

Tags: css, image, drupal, drupal-7, internet-explorer-10

I am trying to allow user to crop their images in Drupal 7.

I am using the imagefield crop module and also tried the manual crop module.

Both work great in Chrome.

In IE10 for imagefield crop the image shrinks and doesn't expand - I end up with large white areas in the preview area. Also the preview squishes the image so as not to keep the aspect ratio.

Bizarrely when the image is then saved it has the proper aspect ratio on display?

For manual crop I get an alert message to say "It appears that some of the images could not be loaded for cropping, please try again in another browser."

It also appears to work fine in IE11 on windows 8 machine...

Thanks for any help!

Comment: This is arguably a Drupal support issue more than a programming issue. It may be on topic on http://drupal.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the edge tools (Developer tools) - f12 on Windows 8 to try and replicate it in IE10

Comment: Mmm?? I am trying to fix it so it won't happen in Ie10 - I want a few people in Australia and America to be able to upload photos.  I am no programmer.  I seem to have this issue with all jcrop modules.  Yet on the dru

Comment: Yet on the drupal modules "try this" pages, using IE10 is fine.  Sorry if I misunderstood you.   If I focus on imagefield crop - half way through the page load I have the picture to be cropped at the bottom and perfect crop above it.  Just as the page finishes loading the top image shrinks to half it's horizontal size and squishes the image.  I have it open on the module issues page but no response - other ppl there are having the same issue??